Monte Carlo Tree Search blundering mate in 1 due to high simulations
I am struggling to understand what should happen when terminal nodes are selected in MCTS. I see there are several posts with similar titles here, here and here but they don't seem to explain my point of difficulty.
Suppose it is white to move, the move W is expanded despite blundering a loss on the next move to the move B and happens to win in play-out. After back-propagation, W has a good score, so a child is chosen to be expanded which is B. B is a terminal node, so we back-propagate a win for black. Now B has a good score. Now I see two possibilities:

Allow B to be selected again (despite it having no child nodes), in which case, B will repeatedly accumulate more and more score as it wins for black every time and keep being selected. Then W will be the most simulated child node of the root node and therefore be selected to be played despite being a blunder (I am selecting the most simulated node based on the wikipedia article).

I do not allow B to be selected again. But I think this poses another problem. If the current state was after the move W, and it was black to move, black would only select B once, despite it winning the game, and then it would not win since it would be simulated less than other moves.


This seems like a very basic part of the algorithm, so I'm sure I have just missed something obvious about how it works.

I think what you miss here is the backpropagation step of the algorithm:
When B is given a good score, then W will receive a bad score during that backpropagation step: W's simulation count will increment, but the number of wins will not (when B was played), so that the ratio of wins over simulations will become low for W.
This bad score of W will make it less likely to be chosen in a next execution of the selection step. Note that the selection phase always starts at the root, so it is expected that after some simulations have been performed, other moves than W will get more attention.
The first scenario of the two you presented will happen, but the following statement in its analysis is not true:

Then W will be the most simulated child node of the root node and therefore be selected to be played despite being a blunder

The number of simulations is not the only factor that determines selection. First of all, the number of wins must be taken into account (as it appears in the numerator), and secondly, the UCB1 formula (See Wikipedia) balances out moves with a lot of simulations against other moves which didn't get much attention yet.
